# Detection the completeness of Annotation's arguments

Tags: java, annotations

This is an example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation

```
  @Author(first = "Oompah", last = "Loompah")
  Book book = new Book();
```

Is it possible to detect whether or not the user provides ALL arguments needed? For example, in this test case, if the argument has ONLY *first = "Oompah"*, it needs to be identified as imcomplete (because of the lack of *last = "Loompah"*). Currently I cannot do that, because if imcomplete arguments are provided, I can get the annotation's **default value**.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: As pointed out by Nikolay, the compiler will force the user to specify a value for every element which does not have a default value. But it you want to _validate_ the values provided you can use an [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html) (though you can't _force_ users to apply the processor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the declaration of the annotation. By default, all arguments are required.

```java
@interface Author {
    String first();
    String last();
}

class Book {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @Author(first = "John")
        Book book = new Book();
    }
}
```

In this example there would be an compile-time error `error: annotation @Author is missing a default value for the element 'last'`.

So, if there is no reason to set a default value for the annotation argument, it should not be marked with `default` in its declaration. And in this case every argument have to be provided.